# Fix problem when install Cuda 7.5 in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: nvidia, software-installation, 18.04, gcc, cuda

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and I want to install `Cuda 7.5` (because this version is compatible with my Nvidia GF 820m graphics card). I configured `gcc-4.8` as default `gcc` for (because it's the Cuda 7.5 C compiler), and I install run file with `sudo ./cuda_7.5.18_linux.run`. 
Here are my terminal output from installing CUDA:

```
    -------------------------------------------------------------
Do you accept the previously read EULA? (accept/decline/quit): accespt
Do you accept the previously read EULA? (accept/decline/quit): accept
You are attempting to install on an unsupported configuration. Do you wish to continue? ((y)es/(n)o) [ default is no ]: y
Install NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64 352.39? ((y)es/(n)o/(q)uit): n
Install the CUDA 7.5 Toolkit? ((y)es/(n)o/(q)uit): y
Enter Toolkit Location [ default is /usr/local/cuda-7.5 ]: 
/usr/local/cuda-7.5 is not writable.
Do you wish to run the installation with 'sudo'? ((y)es/(n)o): y
Please enter your password: 
Do you want to install a symbolic link at /usr/local/cuda? ((y)es/(n)o/(q)uit): y
Install the CUDA 7.5 Samples? ((y)es/(n)o/(q)uit): y
Enter CUDA Samples Location [ default is /home/adel ]: 
Installing the CUDA Toolkit in /usr/local/cuda-7.5 ...
Missing recommended library: libGL.so

Error: cannot find Toolkit in /usr/local/cuda-7.5

===========
= Summary =
===========

Driver:   Not Selected
Toolkit:  Installation Failed
Samples:  Cannot find Toolkit in /usr/local/cuda-7.5

Logfile is /tmp/cuda_install_2279.log
```

It necessary to fix these missing library libGL.so to fix the problem ?

**Note**: Nvidia driver installed is `nvidia-driver-390`

**UPDATE 1**: Output of tail `-n 20 /tmp/cuda_install_2279.log`

```
cp: cannot stat '/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin/.uninstall_manifest_do_not_delete.txt': No such file or directory

Missing recommended library: libGL.so

Error: cannot find Toolkit in /usr/local/cuda-7.5

===========
= Summary =
===========

Driver:   Not Selected
Toolkit:  Installation Failed
Samples:  Cannot find Toolkit in /usr/local/cuda-7.5


Logfile is /tmp/cuda_install_2279.log
```

**UPDATE 2**: Content of the log file:

```
Using more to view the EULA.
Installing the CUDA Toolkit in /usr/local/cuda-7.5 ...
Verifying archive integrity... All good.

Uncompressing NVIDIA CUDA...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Can't locate InstallUtils.pm in @INC (you may need to install the InstallUtils module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26 /usr/share/perl/5.26 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at ./install-linux.pl line 6.

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./install-linux.pl line 6.

Verifying archive integrity... All good.

Uncompressing NVIDIA CUDA Samples................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Can't locate InstallUtils.pm in @INC (you may need to install the InstallUtils module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26 /usr/share/perl/5.26 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at ./install-sdk-linux.pl line 6.

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./install-sdk-linux.pl line 6.

'uninstall_cuda_7.5.pl' -> '/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin/uninstall_cuda_7.5.pl'
```

Comment: Did you find something interesting in /tmp/cuda_install__2279.log? try `tail -n 20 /tmp/cuda_install_2279.log`

Comment: output of `tail -n 20 /tmp/cuda_install_2279.log`
`cp: cannot stat '/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin/.uninstall_manifest_do_not_delete.txt': No such file or directory

Missing recommended library: libGL.so

Error: cannot find Toolkit in /usr/local/cuda-7.5

===========
= Summary =
===========

Driver:   Not Selected
Toolkit:  Installation Failed
Samples:  Cannot find Toolkit in /usr/local/cuda-7.5`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your post when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: post `tail -n 40 /tmp/cuda_install_2279.log` , it seems that there is more info

Comment: Is there a reason why you install cuda7.5 and not cuda9 -> https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/index.html ??? Further it is much better to download the deb file and install with apt ./cuda_file.deb .

Comment: that empty lines are added, same output ! @abu_bua

Comment: but cuda7.5 supports ubuntu15, while cuda9 supports ubuntu17. But it should work.

Comment: thanks @abu_bua. I first tried to install cuda 9 before moving to 7.5 cuda. I fell into this error when running python code: `GPU compute capability 2.1 is not supported (requires> = 2.0)`, the problem that cuda 9 does not support this capability according to some forum

Comment: I fixed the problem by installing cuda 7.5 using Anaconda 
`conda install cudatoolkit=7.5`
Thanks @abu_bua

Comment: it's better to use the repo of ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

Install the following packages:

```
sudo apt install freeglut3-dev build-essential libx11-dev libxmu-dev \
libxi-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev libglfw3-dev libgles2-mesa-dev

sudo apt install sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

---

For Cuda 7.5 installation type this command lines:

```
wget  http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/7.5/Prod/local_installers\
/cuda-repo-ubuntu1504-7-5-local_7.5-18_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1504-7-5-local_7.5-18_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

---

For an easy Cuda 9.1 installation use the instruction given on this [link](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-91-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1704&target_type=deblocal):

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1704-9-1-local_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-<version>/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

---

Or  install it with the default Ubuntu multiverse repo:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-cuda-doc nvidia-cuda-gdb
```

Comment: this package is already installed

Comment: @AdelMadrid: Could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: some new packages are installed, but the same problem! @abu_bua